# With ubuntu/apache how do I keep my website from being viewed from the public while I work on it?

Tags: 14.04

I want to be able to work on the site and view changes in real time but don't want the public (or search engines) to view the site yet.

If there is a way to just allow one ip I'd be happy with that, but I assume there is a better way as I often see "under construction" pages and wonder how they work on the site while it's down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As with all production software, work with at least two versions

- your local Dev version, where all your changes go until you've tested them to your satisfaction.
- your live online version, where you install tested components from your Dev version.

These versions may be on different machines. The process of moving components from Dev to live needs testing also. And of course you'll need to maintain version history and backups of both sites.

Remember to test the backups!